# Where is this CSS located?

Tags: magento2.4.3

I'm trying to change the minimum height in the following CSS:

[image]

But I cannot locate the CSS. When I check link under ".(index)1651" it points to https://domain.com/checkout/cart/:1651

I tried adding the CSS class to a CSS-file, but it gets disabled and the CSS in the screenshot keeps being used.

I have the shop in developer mode.

Any idea where I could find this CSS?

Comment: How you added CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

`(index):1651` means that the CSS is not inside a file. It is inlined in the HTML (on line 1651).

This is not Magento default behaviour.

Either you're using a bought theme, such as Porto, that offers configuration for CSS in the backend.

Or you're using a custom plugin, e.g. for pagespeed optimization, that inlines certain parts of your CSS.

Or somebody has added the CSS to a CMS static block or a special, individually created configuration field.